# When I add two scripts to a html page..one is doesnt work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I created two jquery and and script tags to calender an confirmation ..but when they are in seperate html pages it works well..but it doesnt work when the two scripts are in the same page..Why is that?

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#click').click(function(){
    //$(function() {
        // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {

                    $('#form1').submit();
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsdatepick-calendar/jquery.1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsdatepick-calendar/jsDatePick.jquery.min.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/fadeslideshow.js"></script>
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Why are you loading multiple versions of the jQuery library?

Comment: one might override other.. Please explain your cause/point of errror

Comment: Probably is because you are loading jQuery twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at jQueries no conflict.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

This makes it so you can use certain functions from different jQuery versions/libraries.

Comment: Or, clean up your code and use one version (and save bandwidth and load time)

Answer (score 4):

Try reordering your scripts, it might be causing the problem. You had jQuery in multiple times, this is more than likely the cause of your problems.

Also you should try formatting your code to make it clearer what is going on. For example i have put the script `type` tags at the start for easier readability.

Have you specifically put `Cancel` with no quotes in your dialog? Ive corrected this below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<!--jQuery again here?--><script type="text/javascript" src="jsdatepick-calendar/jsDatePick.jquery.min.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/fadeslideshow.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#click').click(function(){

        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {
                    $('#form1').submit();
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        })
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
( function($$$) {

    $$$(document).ready(function(e) {
        //Code here
    });

} ) ( jQuery );
```