# Multiple scripts not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created two jquery and scripts to build a calender confirmation ..but when they are in seperate html pages it works well..but it doesnt work when the two scripts are in the same page..Why is that?

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script  src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  <script>

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#click').click(function(){
    //$(function() {
        // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {

                        $('#form1').submit();



                    //*****************************************************************
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
    });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsdatepick-calendar/jquery.1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsdatepick-calendar/jsDatePick.jquery.min.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/fadeslideshow.js">

/***********************************************
* Ultimate Fade In Slideshow v2.0- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more
***********************************************/

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Datechooser_____________________
window.onload = function(){
new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"date_created_text",
            dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d"

        });

        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"date_retained_text",
            dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d"

        });

        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"date_to_be_disposed_text",
            dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d"

        });

}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
    wrapperid: "slide", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
    dimensions: [967, 200], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
    imagearray: [
        ["images/img0.jpg", "", "", "The best way to track your files"],
        ["images/img1.jpg", "", "", "The choice for quality service"],
        ["images/img2.jpg", "", "", "With latest technology"],
        ["images/img3.jpg","","","For a safe and secured place"],
        ["images/img4.jpg", "", "", "Better performance with reliable service"],
        ["images/img5.jpg", "", "", "24 x 7 Service"]

         //<--no trailing comma after very last image element!
    ],
    displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:5000, cycles:0, wraparound:false},
    persist:  false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
    fadeduration: 1500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
    descreveal: "peekaboo",
    togglerid: ""
})




</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Blank_TextField_Validator()
{
// Check the value of the element named text_name from the form named text_form
//if (text_form.text_name.value == "")
if(form1.legacy_code_text.value=="" && form1.lable_title_text.value=="" && form1.file_name_text.value=="" && form1.bundle_ref_no_text.value=="" &&form1.bundle_shelf_no_text.value=="" && form1.rack_no_text.value=="" && form1.shelf_no_text.value=="" &&form1.date_created_text.value=="" && form1.date_retained_text.value=="" && form1.date_to_be_disposed_text.value=="" && form1.division_list.value==-1  && form1.unit_list.value==-1 && form1.assignee_code_list.value==-1 && form1.assignee_list.value==-1 && form1.subject_list.value==-1 && form1.serial_no_list.value==-1)
{
  // If null display and alert box
   alert("You have to have even one searching criteria to search files !");
  // Place the cursor on the field for revision

  // return false to stop further processing
   return (false);
}
// If text_name is not null continue processing
return (true);
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I add two scripts to a html page..one is doesnt work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501412/when-i-add-two-scripts-to-a-html-page-one-is-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep only this line:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And remove the following lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsdatepick-calendar/jquery.1.4.2.js"></script>
```

You can't call the jQuery library more than 1 time inside the page.

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: I tried bro..not working yet !

Comment: Kindly paste the new code after your modifications

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsdatepick-calendar/jquery.1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsdatepick-calendar/jsDatePick.jquery.min.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/fadeslideshow.js">

Comment: Remove this line. `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>` and this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="jsdatepick-calendar/jquery.1.4.2.js">`

Comment: The same answer (basicly) for this same Question is [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11501550/1195891).

Comment: @MuhammadReda, **+1** for a good answer.