# multiple java script in one page error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code that is working originally:

```
<th scope="row">
    <select name="Date" required class="form-control" id="Date">
    <option value="">Please Select Date</option>
    <?php $sql2="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die($sql2."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    while($rows2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows2['date'] ?>"><?php echo $rows2['date'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
</th>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Date").change(function(){
        var seldate =$(this).val();
        display_data(seldate);
    });

    // This is the function...
    function display_data(seldate) {

        $("#scheduleDate").html(seldate);
        var dataString = 'seldate='+ seldate;
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getdata.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#Schedule").html(data);
            } 
        });

    }
    // Now here is the real code for retaining your Date...
    <?php
    if (!empty($_GET['date'])) {
        ?>
    display_data('<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?>')
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    document.getElementById('Date').value = '<?php echo @$_GET["date"]; ?>';   
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Name2").change(function(){
        var selname =$(this).val();
        display_name(selname);
    });

    // This is the function...
    function display_name(selname) {

        $("#scheduleName").html(selname);
        var dataString = 'selname='+ selname;
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getdatabyname.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#Schedule2").html(dataname);
            } 
        });

    }
    // Now here is the real code for retaining your Date...
    <?php
    if (!empty($_GET['name'])) {
        ?>
    display_name('<?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>')
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    document.getElementById('Name2').value = '<?php echo @$_GET["name"]; ?>';

});   
</script>
```

getdata.php:

```
<?php
require_once ('../include/global.php');
    if($_POST['seldate']) {
        $selDate = $_POST['seldate'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint WHERE date='$selDate'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
<tr>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['time'] ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['name'] ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['date'] ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><form action='/clinic form/appoint/delete.php'=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>' method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Done">
    </form>

    </td>
    </tr>
<?php } } ?>
```

This gives me a drop down list with dates in to search a table. I want to make a new drop down list but instead of date, I need to display names to make the search, I changed some key words in it, so I added this new code to the same page:

```
<th>
    <select name="Name" required class="form-control" id="Name">
    <option value="">Please Select Name</option>
    <?php $sql3="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint GROUP BY name";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($con, $sql3) or die($sql3."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    while($rows3=mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows3['name'] ?>"><?php echo $rows3['name'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
</th>
```

and make a new php file:

```
<?php
require_once ('../include/global.php');
    if($_POST['selname']) {
        $selDate = $_POST['selname'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint WHERE name='$selname'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
<tr>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['time'] ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['name'] ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['date'] ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><form action='/clinic form/appoint/delete.php'=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>' method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Done">
    </form>

    </td>
    </tr>
<?php } } ?>
```

Now, only the dates list box is working and the other says:
Undefined selname at line 5.
How to fix that. P.S.: I searched those links but none of them helped me:

[When I add two scripts to a html page..one is doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501412/when-i-add-two-scripts-to-a-html-page-one-is-doesnt-work)

[Implications of multiple <script> tags in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659409/implications-of-multiple-script-tags-in-html)

Now I am having the name selected in dropdown list displayed in a div but nothing else with it.

Comment: r u using 2 javascript cdn link in one page?

Comment: I dont know  I am new to js, and if you can fix my code ?

Comment: ok u need only name in dropdown list right?

Comment: Sir, I need both of dropdowns one for date and one for names, plz see my edited codes now

Comment: see my edited code, now the name selected from dropdown list 2 is displayed but not with other data drom sql table

Comment: It is a *profoundly* bad idea to mix PHP and javascript like this. As you're discovering. Recommend finding better tutorials.

Comment: Yes I am experimenting with JS. But I need to finish this code so any help ?

Comment: You use the variable `$selname` in `$sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint WHERE name='$selname'";` but your never created such a variable. Instead you created `$selDate = $_POST['selname'];`

Comment: I fixed it and still have the same problem.Can someone give his email to send the folder to him for code fixing

Comment: What errors do you get now? And we don't do 'send me your email so I can give you my code to fix' problems. Fix your question first.

Comment: you have mistake here `$("#Name2").change(function(){` and the HTML is `<select name="Name" required class="form-control" id="Name">` you binding the JS with wrong id selector, should be same, so fix this by either use `#Name` in JS & HTML `id="Name"` OR `#Name2` in JS & HTML `id="Name2"`

Comment: `Can someone give his email to send the folder to him for code fixing` StackOverflow does not work that way, the best you can get if you want others to fix it for you is build a JSFiddle.

Comment: Fix it and still one of them only works, the date one

Comment: you also have mistake here `success: function(data) { $("#Schedule2").html(dataname); }` should be `success: function(data) { $("#Schedule2").html(data); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in Comments, you made mistakes in your code;

1.Binding `change function` with wrong selector id

```
 $("#Name2").change(function(){
```

and the HTML is

```
<select name="Name" required class="form-control" id="Name">
```

Should be `$("#Name").change(function(){` it will fix the problem *Undefined selname at line 5*

2.*Name* Ajax Method success function

```
success: function(data) {
  $("#Schedule2").html(dataname); 
}
```

Should be `$("#Schedule2").html(data);`

And in PHP; credit goes to @j08691

change `$selDate`

```
$selDate = $_POST['selname'];
```

to `$selname`

```
$selname = $_POST['selname'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint WHERE name='$selname'";
```

As you said in question, your first Ajax Call is working fine and you are facing problem in 2nd Ajax call method, after fixing above mistakes

HTML

```
<th>
    <select name="Name" required class="form-control" id="Name">
    <option value="">Please Select Name</option>
    <?php $sql3="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint GROUP BY name";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($con, $sql3) or die($sql3."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    while($rows3=mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows3['name'] ?>"><?php echo $rows3['name'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
</th>
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Name").change(function(){
        var selname =$(this).val();
        display_name(selname);
    });

    // This is the function...
    function display_name(selname) {
        $("#scheduleName").html(selname);
        var dataString = 'selname='+ selname;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getdatabyname.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#Schedule").html(data);
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
require_once ('../include/global.php');
    if($_POST['selname']) {
        $selname = $_POST['selname'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint WHERE name='$selname'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
<tr>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['time'] ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['name'] ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['date'] ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><form action='/clinic form/appoint/delete.php'=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>' method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Done">
    </form>

    </td>
    </tr>
<?php } } ?>
```

(OP reached me via email and explained what he is trying to do)
Now, you are fetching result by 2 different `<select>` element using Ajax and trying to show the result based on `<select>` element and in both Ajax calls `success: function` you are targeting 2 different `id's` to show the data for each `<select>` Ajax call e.g

```
//For Date Result
$("#Schedule").html(data);
//For Name Result
$("#Schedule2").html(data);
```

I would suggest to use the same `id` selector in both Ajax calls `success: function` to show the data

```
$("#Schedule").html(data);
```

By doing so, when you switch between select element, to show the data, it will replace the first fetched data.

Last, I totally agree with @Jared Smith what he said about mixing PHP and JavaScript, it's really not good practice.

Comment: Thanks I will do just what you said in the last part and for the code it works now, thank you.