# Including JS file in html page errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this JavaScript code inside an html and PHP page. But I've been told that it will works only if I had an internet connection, so the solution was to make a .JS file and include this file inside the page like that:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/clinic form/appoint/dropscript.js">
</script>
```

Now I got an error while testing the page offline.

[image: Those are the errors]

The JS file is taken from this link:
[multiple java script in one page error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434692/multiple-java-script-in-one-page-error/33439374#33439374)

And the final code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Date").change(function(){
        var seldate =$(this).val();
        display_data(seldate);
    });

    // This is the function...
    function display_data(seldate) {

        $("#scheduleDate").html(seldate);
        var dataString = 'seldate='+ seldate;
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getdata.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#Schedule").html(data);
            } 
        });

    }
    // Now here is the real code for retaining your Date...
    /*<?php
    if (!empty($_GET['date'])) {
        ?>
    display_data('<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?>')
        <?php
    }
    ?>*/
    document.getElementById('Date').value = '<?php echo @$_GET["date"]; ?>';

});



$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Name").change(function(){
        var selname =$(this).val();
        display_name(selname);
    });

    // This is the function...
    function display_name(selname) {
        $("#scheduleName").html(selname);
        var dataString = 'selname='+ selname;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getdatabyname.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#Schedule").html(data);
            } 
        });
    }
});// JavaScript Document
```

P.S. I am totally new to JS and I am experimenting.

Comment: If you don't have  internet connection then it will not be able to load. so copy the js and css and save in directory

Comment: Learn how to run a local server for developping locally: http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/why-you-need-a-testing-server-and-how-to-do-it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js, hit CTRL+S, move saved file to your project's directory and then include it as you did with dropscript.js.

Also do the same with the font if you need it. Include it into your CSS file using `@font-face`. More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face